# Ext.form.Panel submit() timeout not being enforced

Tags: extjs, extjs4, submit

I have an `Ext.form.Panel` that I am creating and submitting.  I am basically creating and submitting a large `.xml` file that is then posted back to the server.

I am using the `standardSubmit` option because of file size constraints with AJAX request

My issue is that the timeout appears to not be enforced with `standardSubmit` set to `true`?  It appears to be timing out at 30 sec.

Here is the relevant code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    url: 'serverUrlForPost',
    standardSubmit: true,
    timeout:180,
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'textarea'
    },
    items: [{
        name: 'filetype',
        value: this.filetype
    }, {
        name: 'data',
        value: this.data
    }]
}).getForm().submit();
```

Comment: I think that in your case timeout is caused by server side. When you are using standard submit you can not control timeout on client side.

Comment: @Akatum Okay, I'll check out the server-side code for the timeouts set. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BY following your example, it should be like,

```js
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
 url : 'serverUrlForPost',
 standardSubmit : true,
 timeout : 180,
 defaults : {
  xtype : 'textarea'
 },
 items : [{
   name : 'filetype',
   value : this.filetype
  }, {
   name : 'data',
   value : this.data
  }
 ]
}).getForm().submit({
 timeout:20, // 20 Seconds
 success : function (form, action) {
  alert("success")
 },
 failure : function (form, action) {
  alert("Failed")
 }
});
```

[Check this link for more info](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Action)